# What is the right place to create secondary constructor in kotlin class?

Tags: kotlin

what is the right place to create the secondary constructor above the init block or below it ?

```
class Bottle(bottleShape: String, capacity: Int, color: String): Container( bottleShape, capacity) {

private var closed: Boolean = true
    val bottleColor: String

 constructor(bottleShape: String, capacity: Int): this (bottleShape, capacity, "Transparent")

    init{

        closeAble = true
        bottleColor = color
        println(bottleColor)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a convention, obviously, however following [the official documentation on class layout](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#class-layout), that calls for order:

> - **Property declarations and initializer blocks**
> - **Secondary constructors**
> - Method declarations
> - Companion object

I would put initialisation ahead of secondary constructor.